# Angular Velocity and Angular acceleration when the position vector is changing

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

[image]
I was watching a lecture about circular motion and how angular velocity and angular acceleration differ if origin changes.The teacher at [9:10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9Bnn9igtCI&t=9m1s) says that we cannot apply the formula $a=rα$ as position vector $r$ changes about $O$. But at the starting while calculating angular velocity , he used $v=rω$. $r$ changes in this case too, so how did he directly apply it in this case.

I have been so restless since then and I searched all over the internet but couldn't get a proper reason. At last, this is the only hope remains. I am looking for an answer which clears the basics as how to calculate angular velocity and angular acceleration when position vector varies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is simply the general formula for acceleration in polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$:
$$\mathbf{r} = r \hat{\mathbf{r}} \\ \dot{\mathbf{r}} = \dot{r}\hat{\mathbf{r}} + r \dot{\theta}\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}} \\ \ddot{\mathbf{r}} = \left(\ddot{r} - r \dot{\theta}^2\right)\hat{\mathbf{r}} + \left(r \ddot{\theta} + 2\dot{r}\dot{\theta}\right)\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}$$

To show this, all you have to do is to start from the first line and take successive time derivatives of the position vector. Note that $\mathrm{d}\hat{\mathbf{r}}/\mathrm{d}\theta = \hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}$ and $\mathrm{d}\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}/\mathrm{d}\theta = -\hat{\mathbf{r}}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but can you pls explain this simply, I'm not familiar with polar coordinates. Thank you

Comment: I think i should have specified that but sorry

Comment: I looked up some videos for polar coordinates and i think i get your notations now. Except I don't get this "Note that $dr^/dθ=θ^$
 and $dθ^/dθ=−r^$"

Comment: : angular velocity= $v_{transverse}/r$; But angular acceleration is $(a_{transverse}-2ωv_{radial})/r$
. Is that correct?

Comment: @PinkAura $\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ and $\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}$ are the polar basis unit vectors. They point in the radial and tangential directions respectively. Unlike their Cartesian counterparts, they vary with position (in fact, they vary with $\theta$). Therefore their derivatives must be taken as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since OP's comments still show confusion I'd like to expand Vincent Thacker's very good answer a bit.

Using
\begin{align}
\hat{\mathbf{r}}&=(\cos\theta)\,\hat{\mathbf{x}}+(\sin\theta)\,\hat{\mathbf{y}}\,,\\
\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}&=-(\sin\theta)\,\hat{\mathbf{x}}+(\cos\theta)\,\hat{\mathbf{y}}\,,\\
\end{align}
we see
$$
\frac{d\hat{\mathbf{r}}}{d\theta}=\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}\,,\quad \frac{d\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}}{d\theta}=-\hat{\mathbf{r}}\,,
$$
so that
$$
\frac{d\hat{\mathbf{r}}}{dt}=\dot\theta\,\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}\,,\quad \frac{d\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}}{d\theta}=-\dot\theta\,\hat{\mathbf{r}}\,.
$$
This leads to
\begin{align}
\mathbf{r} &= r\,\hat{\mathbf{r}}\tag{position}\,,\\[2mm] 
\dot{\mathbf{r}} &= \underbrace{\dot{r}\,\hat{\mathbf{r}}}_{\text{radial}} + \underbrace{r\, \dot{\theta}\,\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}}_{\text{transverse}}\tag{velocity}\,, \\[2mm] 
\ddot{\mathbf{r}} 
&=\underbrace{\left(\ddot{r} - r \,\dot{\theta}^2\right)\hat{\mathbf{r}}}_{\text{radial}} + \underbrace{\left(r \,\ddot{\theta} + 2\,\dot{r}\,\dot{\theta}\right)\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}}_{\text{transverse}}\,.\tag{acceleration}
\end{align}
In the [literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity#Particle_in_two_dimensions) we can also see the notation
$$\tag{velocity}
\dot{\mathbf{r}} = \underbrace{v_{\|}\,\hat{\mathbf{r}}}_{\text{radial}} + \underbrace{v_{\bot}\,\hat{\boldsymbol{\theta}}}_{\text{transverse}}
$$
and the definition of spin angular velocity as $\frac{v_\bot}{r}=\frac{v\sin\theta}{r}$ which unsurprisingly turns out to be
$$
\dot\theta=\frac{v_\bot}{r}\,.
$$

In the video, $\mathbf{r}$ moves in a circle of radius $R$ around the point $(2R,0)$ with uniform circular motion.
Presumably this means that that angular velocity $\omega$ with respect to
$(2R,0)$ is constant.

But this $\omega$ is ***different*** from $\dot\theta\,!$
To answer a question in your comment: it is ***not*** correct that angular
acceleration is
$$
\frac{a_{transverse}-2\omega\, v_{radial}}{r}\,.
$$
You seem to arrive at this by plugging $\omega=\dot\theta$ (wrong!)
into the (acceleration) formula and solving for $\ddot\theta\,$.

To finish the task they pose in the video:

They want you to show that when the particle is at point
$A=(2R,2R)$
its transverse angular acceleration is
$$\tag{1}
R\,\omega^2\,\cos\theta=\frac{2\,R\,\omega^2}{\sqrt{5}}\,.
$$
The approach they take is very smart: in the system where $(2R,0)$ is the
origin the particle has only radial acceleration of magnitude
$$
R\omega^2
$$
To see this apply the (acceleration) formula to this coordinate system and
observe that most terms vanish.
Then a simple geometrical argument leads to (1) in the original coordinate system
where $r$ is changing.

Comment: "  is different from ˙", i was referring to it in general, and not according to the video. are they still different? I believe they are same (as I watched in some of the videos)

Comment: @PinkAura It is pointless to refer to notation in general and compare how they use that in videos. Any discussion using notation should include their clear meaning.

Comment: i don't get you, forget the notations, does "˙" represent angular velocity?

Comment: if so, then is my relation for angular acceleration correct?

Comment: In that context $\dot\theta$ is angular velocity, and $\ddot\theta$ is angular acceleration. Transverse acceleration is what I underbraced and called "transverse". This should enable you to rewrite your relation in clean fashion.

Comment: Thank you, yes, i did not count coriolis acceleration in transverse acceleration, my bad